# Saber si un numero n/4 da entero PHP

Tags: php

He hecho esto:

```
$year=2016  
if(($year%4)==1){
    ...
}
```

Me gustaría saber si un número dividido entre 4, su resultado es entero, es decir.

2016/4 = 504, por lo tanto entraría en el if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es justo como lo estás haciendo, pero cambiando el valor de la comparación.

```
$year=2016  
if(($year%4)==0){
    ...
}
```

El operador `%` devuelve el **resto** de la división. Si la división es **exacta** (sin resto), devuelve `0`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :D